# Which of the following is an equation for the graph shown?

Tags: calculus

Which of the following is an equation for the graph shown?

I think the answer is c for because I  think we know hte ampiltude is 3 and and it has 4 periods? please correct me if I'am wrong.

[image]

Comment: is it supposed to be $\frac{\pi}{2}$ instead of $\pi$ in the graph?

Comment: There's no labels for the intervals on the graph, and it looks like there's a denominator under the $\pi$ that's missing.

Comment: Indeed, if the graph is correct as it is, then none of the answers fit the graph. Instead the correct function would be $\sin(\frac{3x}{2})$

Comment: I added the correct graph now :D

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Plug in some concrete $x$ values, like $x=\pi/2$ or $x=\pi/3$.

Answer (score 0):

Given the updated graph:

Note that the amplitude of the wave is $\left|\dfrac{1 - (-1)}{2}\right| = \dfrac 22 = 1$. There is no phase shift.

From viewing the wave length ("width") of one period we see the period looks to be $2\pi/3$, which we can obtain when we divide $2\pi$ by $\color{blue}{\bf 3}$: So $3$ is desired coefficient of $x$, and we see that option $(D)$ gives us the desired function.$(\dagger)$ Indeed, we can evaluate the function $$(D) \quad y =  \sin 3x$$ when $x = \pi/2, y = -1$, and when $x = -\pi/2, y = 1,$ both values corresponding to the graph, as desired. **So $(D)$ is the correct option here.**

---

$(\dagger)$ We know that the period of the function is $\dfrac{2\pi}{3}$ by gauging the distance of the period, horizontally: the given graph shows two complete periods, each symmetrical around the y-axis. Let's use $c$ to denote the coefficient of the variable $x$ in the corresponding equation. Then we need $c$ so that $$\frac{2\pi}{|c|} = \;\text{period}\;\; =\dfrac{2\pi}{3}.$$

Solving for $c$ gives us $|c| = 3 \implies c = \pm 3$. So we know that the coefficient $c$ of $x$ in the equation $y = \sin(cx)$ must be $c = 3$, given our choices. So the coefficient $c$ is not equivalent to the period of the function, but knowing that the period is equal to $2\pi$ divided by $|c|$ allows us to determine what that value is.